# Dynamic model binding client side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, model-binding

I am creating an asp.net MVC razor page wherein i have to dynamically add /delete model using jQuery (all at client side).The models need to be added/deleted not only at the end of the list but can be deleted/added at any position in the list. How do I handle the models (indexs of model) in such scenario so that I have to post the model binded data to controller

Currently, I am cloning the data like this,

```
var $newPanel = $currentPanel.clone().removeAttr('id');
```

and assigning objects like this

```
$('#id1', $newPanel).attr('name', 'CurrentDateTrips[' + index + '].Vehicle');
```

Comment: if i add an element in the middle,i ll have to update all other elements.The main question is how to handle elements such that element can be deleted/added anywhere in list

Comment: Have a read of: https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

To use the default MVC list binding, the indexes need to be *sequential* (ie 1,2,3, not 1,3,4).

However, the indexes don't need to be in that order in the html, as long as they are sequential in the post.

For deletions, don't `.remove()` the rows, but have a *logical delete* (eg hidden input with with name=rowdeleted or so).  This way the sequences stays sequential when deleting rows.

Adding new rows in the middle becomes the same as adding them at the end, the index is existing rows / highest index + 1.  But can be anywhere in the actual rows, no need to re-index.

Comment: i tried this,but while deleting/adding,i will not know for which index that action is to be performed,coz indexes will be not in order.For getting the index,i will have to read the html  i guess.

Comment: Yes, your delete button would be something like (this=button) `var id = $(this).closest("tr").data("index")` where `<tr data-index="@index">`  or `$(this).closest("tr").hide().find(".hiddendeleteinput").val(true)`  if you're using nth-index for stripes then you might need to remove the row but have the `<input name="hidden[idx]">` inputs outside the rows

Comment: Yes,using data- is really helpful.Worked for me.Thankyou